# Массив маркеров и InfoWindow (API V3)

Tags: google-maps-api, javascript

В документации по картам гугл описывается пример открытия одного инфоокон для одного маркера:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title:"Uluru (Ayers Rock)"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Мне нужно завести на карту много маркеров, чтобы у каждого было свое инфоокно с данными из моего заранее подготовленного массива. Однако, простая замена переменных `marker`, `infowindow` на массивы `marker[]`, `infowindow[]` в цикле - нужного результата не дала.
По щелчку на любом маркере вылетает инфоокно последнего поставленного маркера.
Подскажите, где искать ошибку или пример под такую задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой рейтинг вырос, поэтому появилась возможность ответить самому себе. Итак:

```
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
         position: myCenter, 
         map: map, 
         title: 'Объект: '+devices[i][1],
         icon:image }); 
         // devices[] - это заранее подготовленный массив с полной информацией по каждому объекту, i - счетчик в цикле, остальные переменные также определены изначально
      mArray.push(marker);
      mArray[i].setMap(map); // маркеры храню для выборочной обработки (необязательно)
      makeInfoWin(marker, html); // html - заранее подгогтовленный текст в виде хтмл-разметки, который будет выведен в текущем инфоокне
      }
}  

function makeInfoWin(marker, data) {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: data });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });  

  }
```

API v.3

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое!
Правда при вставке этого кода возникла ошибка в функции `makeInfoWin`, а именно 
`undefined var "map"`, пришлось немного дописать её, передав в неё соотв. параметр.

Строка вызова:

```
makeInfoWin(marker, html, map);

function makeInfoWin(marker, data, map) {  // добавили map

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: data });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    infowindow.open(map,marker);

  });  
}
```

Comment: map - это  глобальная переменная, она объявляется однократно в начале кода, как и во всех примерах из Google Maps API v3.0 Samples

то, что написали вы - будет при каждом вызове создавать новую карту, что будет излишне расходовать ресурсы.